# How to choose which array to loop through before running awk for loop?

Tags: arrays, awk, variable-assignment

Using awk (not gawk) I would like to iterate through one of two arrays, depending on the value of a separate variable. One array contains a subset of the data in the other. I have a large `for` loop so would prefer not to just use `if() { for() {} } else { for() {} }` syntax and double the length of my code. I want to use the same `for` loop on only one of the two arrays.

Do I have to use two `for` loops? I also don't really want to iterate any more values than I have to.

Here I was hoping either of the two arrays to be selected depending on the value of `independent_variable`, but this code gives a syntax error at the first of the enclosed brackets (and besides, there wouldn't be a concrete array name to reference in the loop):

```
for (i in (independent_variable ? array1 : array2)) {
    # process the selected array
}
```

Otherwise, is it not possible to create a new temporary array from one of the original ones, without using `for` loops to populate the temporary array? This gives an error saying that I'm treating the arrays like scalars:

```
if (independent_variable) { relevant_array = array1 }
else { relevant_array = array2 }

for (i in relevant_array)
{
    # process the selected array
}
```

---

EDIT: Here is my code that calls a function containing the `for` loop, using a ternary operator. It doesn't work (error message below):

**ternary_exp_for.awk**

```
function do_loop(arr,   i) {
    for (i in arr) {
        print "within function: " i arr[i]
    }
}

END {
    array1[1]="abc"
    array1[2]="def"
    array2[1]="ABC"
    array2[2]="DEF"
    for (i in array1) {
        print "outside function, array1: " array1[i]
    }
    for (j in array2) {
        print "outside function, array2: " array2[j]
    }
    
    independent_variable=0
    print "\nwith independent_variable == " independent_variable
    do_loop(independent_variable ? array1 : array2)
    
    independent_variable=1
    print "\nwith independent_variable == " independent_variable
    do_loop(independent_variable ? array1 : array2)
}
```

Running `awk -f ternary_exp_for.awk <<< "test"` gives me this output, and error:

```
outside function, array1: abc
outside function, array1: def
outside function, array2: ABC
outside function, array2: DEF

with independent_variable == 0
awk: ternary_exp_for.awk:21: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array `array2' in a scalar context
```

Comment: consider updating the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), to include a couple (small) `awk` arrays, the variable you're testing, and the expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't save the name of an array in a scalar variable, nor can you create a pointer to an array, nor can you copy an array by assignment.

Containing common code is one of the reasons functions exist so put the loop in a function and call it with the appropriate array name, e.g.:

```
function do_loop(arr,     i) {
    for ( i in arr ) {
        print i, arr[i]
    }
}
```

Call it using a ternary expression:

```
{ independent_variable ? do_loop(array1) : do_loop(array2) }
```

or just an if-else:

```
{ if (independent_variable) do_loop(array1); else do_loop(array2) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the working bits in a function to avoid unnecessary duplication:

```
function my_for(arr){
    for (e in arr) print e,arr[e]
}
```

Then use an `if` or conditional to choose your array:

```
if (condition) {my_for(array_a)} else {my_for(array_b)}
```